# Consider $ x $ real in the equation below and satisfying the equation:

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

$\frac {1} {x ^ 3-1} + \frac {2} {x ^ 3-2} + \frac {3} {x ^ 3-3  } + \frac {4}{x ^ 3-4} = 2x ^ 4 - 5x - 4.$

Note: $x ^ 3 \neq1, 2, 3,$ and $4$. Determine the value of: $x ^ 6-5x ^ 3 =  ?$

I think it would be more feasible to create a polynomial that has as roots the 4 terms $(\frac {1} {x ^ 3-1} ....)$ and use Girard

But arriving at $ y ^ 2 + 10y + 24 = x ^ 2 $ you can not do anything right?

answer:
$\sqrt{2}-4$ or $-\sqrt{2}-4$

Comment: $x=(5/2)^{1/3}$ is a solution of the equation, but $x^6-5x^3=-25/4$. Maybe those two are not the only expected answers. Are there other conditions on $x$?

Comment: @conditionalMethod I think there's more

Comment: Yes, for each root of $x (x^3 - x - 2) (2 x^3 - 5) (x^9 + x^7 - 8 x^6 - x^5 - 6 x^4 + 18 x^3 + 2 x^2 + 6 x - 12)$ there is a value. For example, $x=0$ is also a solution, and therefore, $0$ another value that $x^6-5x^3$ can take.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Can you detail in an answer?

Comment: Well, that polynomial is just the numerator of the fraction obtained when add everything on a single side of the equation. Obtained and factored by a computer. It looks like it is not a problem like similar ones that are nicely designed to have only very few answers.

Comment: Be like Euler. Proceed straightforwardly.